# Format x-axis date in chr type on facet_wrap using R

Tags: r, as.date

*** Updated code so it is reproducible.  ***

This question relates to R using RStudio.

I need to format the date on the x-axis as three-letter month and two-digit day, as shown below (Mar 01).

The date is a dataframe itself as date.local, it's  of type "chr", and in this format: 2021-04-10T20:00:00+02:00

This is the code I'm using on R:

```
measurements_page <- fromJSON("https://api.openaq.org/v2/measurements?coordinates=41.385063,2.173404&radius=1200&limit=2000#/")
```

```
measurements_df <- as_tibble(measurements_page$results)
# Tried as.Date() but I couldn't get it to work 
#as.Date(measurements_df$date$local, format = "%m/%d/%Y" )
```

```
measurements_df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(
     x = date$local, 
     y = value,
     group = 1
  )) +
  facet_wrap(~ parameter, scales = "free_y")
```

It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

But it looks like this:

[image]

It appears to me like the dates are all superimposed on top of each other in the long format.

How can I fix this?

I tried this:

```
as.Date(measurements_df$date$local, format = "%m/%d/%Y" )
```

But I'm getting all NA's

Help is appreciated. Please and Thank you!

Comment: 1) `date$local` and `value` are separate data sets? That's not a good idea; 2) Can you post sample data? Like this the question's problem is not reproducible; 3) see `scale_x_datetime`, argument `date_labels = "%b %d"`.

Comment: Updated code. date is a dataframe within the main dataframe. I hope I am explaining this correctly.

Comment: @Rui Barradas. Thank you Rui Barradas. I tried to use `ymd()` from lubridate on the data set but had no success. No change in `date.utc`. How do you encouter that date$lcoal and value are separate datasets? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To se the structure of the data, use `str()`. You will see that `date` is a data.frame of  variables, so `date$local` is the vector to be in plotted the x axis. (Or `date$utc`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrapped x variable is `aes` around `as.Date` and it worked in my window

```
measurements_df %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(
    x = as.Date(date$local), 
    y = value,
    group = 1
  )) +
  facet_wrap(~ parameter, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple I just didn't know where to fit the as.Date().

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Though there already is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67042289/8245406), here is another one.
I have some doubts on a line graph of these data, see below a scatter plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

measurements_page <- jsonlite::fromJSON("https://api.openaq.org/v2/measurements?coordinates=41.385063,2.173404&radius=1200&limit=2000#/")

measurements_page %>% 
  magrittr::extract2("results") %>%
  mutate(date_local = as.Date(date$local)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date_local, value)) +
  #geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Date local") +
  facet_wrap(~ parameter, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]